# Shouldn't the Community auto-link fixer also fix the text?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, community-user, broken-link

I noticed that this answer was updated by the Community user to fix a presumably broken link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/177007/5987

Now though the text gives one address while the actual link is to another address. They started out the same; shouldn't the auto fixer detect this and change both at the same time?

I was tempted to edit the answer and fix it myself, but I thought the devs might appreciate seeing it in its original state.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, it would. However, this user had *explicitly set* the URL as the description of the link also (look at the side-by-side Markdown). If he had just entered the plain link and let the system automatically make it into a hyperlink, then editing it manually would not be necessary.

Really, this is an edge-case that just isn't worth looking at. This isn't normal behavior, as using that syntax you're expected to enter an *actual description* for the link, not enter the link itself again.

Answer (score 2):

That wasn't the auto-link fixer (which so far as I'm aware isn't actively fixing link just yet); that was an anonymous reader [submitting an improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/765411).

But yeah, [as animuson mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171238/shouldnt-the-community-auto-link-fixer-also-fix-the-text/171239#171239), the way that link was set up *would* probably make life weird for automation as well.